# Contact Form 7: Set default date to today

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How do I set the default date to today, using Contact Form 7?

The minimum date can be set easily with `min:today`. When you click on a datepicker you can choose dates from today.

But the default date (before picking) is not today's date. The date is displayed like 2016/mm/dd or whatever date format.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I added a script

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
   var now = new Date(); 
   var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
  $('#datePicker').val(today);
$("#datePicker").attr("min", today);
});
</script>
```

And than call it in:

```
[date* your-date class:required id:datePicker]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use relative date/time functions supported by the DateTime class. So, adding "today" works to set it as a default date. ([Specifying a Date with Relative Date Formats](https://contactform7.com/date-field/#specifying-a-date-with-relative-date-formats))

```
[date due-date "today"]
```

Comment: This is the easiest way and should be the accepted answer. 

Answer (score 1):

I found:

```
$(function() {
var now = new Date(); 
   var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
  $('#datePicker').val(today);
$("#datePicker").attr("min", today);
});
```

Also, Don't Forget to add the library at first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have called it as:

```
[date* check-in min:today id:datePicker]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min:today` without using JavaScript or Jquery functions, see: [date field](https://contactform7.com/date-field/)

```
[date* check-in min-date:today placeholder "Date"]
```