# Contact Form 7 won't parse date?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've tried this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 custom-row">
  [date your-datearrivo class:form-control date-format:DD/MM/YYYY min:today]
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 custom-row">
  [date your-datepartenza class:form-control date-format:DD/MM/YYYY min:today+7days]
</div>
```

But it outputs this:

[image]

i.e. it doesnt init dates values as 12/02/2019 (today) and 19/02/2019 (today+7days). Just set min/max (which I don't need).

How can I display today + today+7days when I open the page where I have the Contact Form?

Comment: Hi, can you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893462/contact-form-7-set-default-date-to-today) ? It may answer your question

Comment: @IceAx: js? Uhm... I'd like to manage front end side

Comment: I agree it's not very clean as solution.. Try by putting an * after `date`, like this `[date* your-datearrivo...]`

Comment: @IceAx: ? That's only for requirements. Nothing change...

Comment: I tested a little bit on my side too. I think that the placeholder text, `gg/mm/aaaa` in your case is generated by the HTML render engine of your browser, Chrome in your case. You must use JS like it said in the thread above. If someone find another way, I'll be glad to hear it too.